# Was the width of the Atlantic first determined in 1584?

Tags: astronomy

In [Eclipse: Journeys to the Dark Side of the Moon](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Eclipse.html?id=BxcxDgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) by Frank Close, it is stated that the 1584 lunar eclipse was used to determine the width of the Atlantic, by measuring the times in London and in Virginia. However, I cannot seem to find any other source, except at [his RI talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6JZSzVcKgo).

I would like to know if this claim is true, and if yes, some more historical details (such as the names of the people involved) on it.

Note that the question is *not* about the methodology, but about the *historical fact*, whether or not the claimed measurement happened. It would also be great to know about histories of measurements similar to this.

In contrast, [this related question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6616/why-was-in-1584-the-eclipse-of-the-moon-used-to-calculate-the-width-of-the-atlan) focuses on the basic methodical aspect of such measurements.

Comment: It was well-known that "time equals longitude", and a method for determining it using lunar eclipses was proposed already [by Hipparchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipparchus#Astronomical_instruments_and_astrometry) (marking the difference in local times when the eclipse is observed). Vespucci claimed to have used this method in 1502. One can then find the distance between London and Virginia knowing the latitudes and the circumference of the Earth.

Comment: @Conifold: I was not asking how it is possible, but whether the claimed event happened.

Comment: Thomas Harriott springs to mind as someone who might have done this, except he did not seem to arrive in Virginia until 1585, and does not seem to mention it in his _Brief and true report..._ .

Comment: Spaniards arranged global observation of eclipses in 1570-80s, including 1584:"*What makes the enterprise remarkable is the sponsorship and the execution. Preparations were made under the auspices of the Royal Academy of Mathematics in Madrid and the Royal Council well enough ahead of time to supply observers in Antwerp, Venice, Sevilla, Toledo, Madrid, and Mexico City with identical instructions for an "instrumento", i.e., a uniform-sized sheet containing a half circle of the same radius, to register the sightings.*" [see Lamb](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/tin.1974.6.1.51).

Comment: Timur, you question is "Was ... **first determined** ..."  So Conifold's comments on earlier measurements is valid.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I did not say anybody's comment is invalid. In fact the one who upvoted his comment is me.